# AWSWebIdentityCredentialsProvider How to get parameters values?

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-web-services

Am trying to use the below code to do authentication,

But i am unable to get the values needs to be passed to following parameters,
***providerId, roleArn, roleSessionName.***

However, webIdentityToken value i will receive it from our local server.

```
AWSWebIdentityCredentialsProvider *provideer = [AWSWebIdentityCredentialsProvider credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 providerId:@"" roleArn:@"" roleSessionName:"" webIdentityToken:@""];
```

Regards,
Bhat

Comment: Hello, you might want to consider using [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/). It offers the same provider support as web identity federation through STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created custom credential provider and amazon authentication mechanism works flawlessly :) .
I have followed the steps same as that of Static Credential provider.

Comment: Can you give me you code sample? I'm trying to do the same thing. My boss insisted on not using cognito at all so I need to do this.

Comment: @tyegah123 I have added the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
Class.h 
-------

@interface AWSCustomCredentialProvider : NSObject <AWSCredentialsProvider>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *accessKey;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *secretKey;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *sessionKey;

+ (instancetype)credentialsWithAccessKey:(NSString *)accessKey
                               secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey sessionKey:
(NSString*)sessionKey;

+ (instancetype)credentialsWithCredentialsFilename:(NSString *)credentialsFilename;

- (instancetype)initWithAccessKey:(NSString *)accessKey
                        secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey sessionKey:(NSString*)sessionKey;


@end

Class.m 
-------
+ (instancetype)credentialsWithAccessKey:(NSString *)accessKey
                               secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey sessionKey:(NSString*)sessionKey
{
    AWSCustomCredentialProvider *credentials = [[AWSCustomCredentialProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:accessKey
                                                                                              secretKey:secretKey sessionKey:sessionKey];
    return credentials;
}
+ (instancetype)credentialsWithCredentialsFilename:(NSString *)credentialsFilename
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:credentialsFilename ofType:@"json"];
    NSDictionary *credentialsJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                                                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                      error:nil];
    AWSCustomCredentialProvider *credentials = [[AWSCustomCredentialProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:credentialsJson[@"accessKey"]
                                                                                              secretKey:credentialsJson[@"secretKey"] sessionKey:credentialsJson[@"sessionKey"]];
    return credentials;
}
- (instancetype)initWithAccessKey:(NSString *)accessKey
                        secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey sessionKey:(NSString*)sessionKey
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _accessKey = accessKey;
        _secretKey = secretKey;
        _sessionKey = sessionKey;
    }
    return self;
}
Usage is: 
-----
 AWSCustomCredentialProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCustomCredentialProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AccessKey_Element] secretKey:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SecretKey_Element] sessionKey:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:Token_Element]];
```